# Efficient way to create matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix like this from a vector:

```
    vec= c(2, 5, 9)
    > A
            [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]     2    0    0    0
    [2,]     5    3    0    0
    [3,]     9    7    4    0
```

Actually always the first column is the vector element, the second column start with 0 and then the (5-2 = 3) and then the thirld element of second column is (9-2 = 7). Then the third column start with 0 and then 0 and (9-5 = 4) and the last column is always zero. May be the length of vec changes to any number for example 4, 5,... .How can I write an efficient function or code to create this matrix?

Comment: I don't understand where the other 3 columns (after the first) in your matrix came from? You say you want to create a matrix from 'a' vector, but then your matrix looks like it was built from 4 of them, all the same length. But then you suggest the lengths of the vectors can be different? I think you need to make it a little bit clearer what you want to do.

Comment: Actually always the first column is the vector element, the second column start with 0 and then the (5-2 = 3) and then the thirld element of second column is (9-2 = 7). Then the third column start with 0 and then 0 and (9-5 = 4) and the last column is always zero. May be the length of $vec$ changes to any number for example 4, 5,...

Comment: @BensorBeny: That helps, thanks.  Please edit your question with that information, and also specify how this is different than the stackoverflow question.

Comment: @BensorBeny: Thanks for the edit.  This sounds a lot like the stackoverflow question, though, for which you checked the mark saying you got an answer that worked for you.  Is this different?  How?

Comment: @Aaron: Actually that one is a simple case, and I thought that that works for every vector, but when i changed my vector I have seen this is not my desire. This above matrix which is different form that one is my purpose.

Comment: The original verison of this question referred to is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10826357/210673).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
f = function(vec)
{
   n = length(vec)  
   M = matrix(0,n,n+1)
   M[,1] = vec
   for(i in 1:n) M[,i+1] = c(rep(0,i),vec[-c(1:i)]-vec[i])
   return(M)
}

vec = c(2,5,9)
f(vec)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    0    0    0
[2,]    5    3    0    0
[3,]    9    7    4    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly my desire matrix. but is there any other more efficeint way to avoid for loop?

Comment: No problem, @BensorBeny. If you've found this answer helpful please consider upvoting/accepting it :)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about efficiency, but here are two solutions without using for loops:

```
n <- length(vec)    
A <- replicate(n+1, vec) - cbind(0, t(replicate(n, vec)))
A[upper.tri(A)] <- 0
```

This one is longer but creates only one matrix

```
n <- length(vec)
A <- replicate(n, vec)
A <- A - t(A)
A <- cbind(vec, A)
A[upper.tri(A)] <- 0
```

Comment: Just i am wondering why the second answer without for loop have more system.time for large length vector than the fisrt answer function with for loop? As far as i know, for loop always increase the system.time and gets the code less efficient. Is it right always or not?

Comment: No, that's not always true. [It's complicated.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8474941/210673) [Clarity is also a virtue.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2275896/210673)